# preg_match_all between two sentences

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

from the phrase:

```
 <div class="latestf"> <a href="http://www.x.ro/anamaria/"
 rel="nofollow"
```

I want to extract anamaria. How to do that with preg_match_all ?

I tried:

```
preg_match_all("'<div class=\"latestf\">
<a href=\"http://www.x.ro/(.*?)\" rel=\"nofollow\"'si", $source, $match);
```

but it didn`t work...

Thank you in advance !

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: edited now with code quotes

Comment: it just returns no result..like i`ve missed something

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Is the newline in the regex intentional? Also, you should escape your periods: `.` -> `\.`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$source = '<div class="latestf"> <a href="http://www.x.ro/anamaria/" rel="nofollow"';


preg_match_all('#<div\s*class="latestf">\s*<a\s*href="http://www\.x\.ro/(.*?)/?"\s*rel="nofollow"#i', $source, $match);

print_r($match);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <div class="latestf"> <a href="http://www.x.ro/anamaria/" rel="nofollow"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => anamaria
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to parse HTML with regex. Use a [DOM parser](http://php.net/dom) instead:

```
$html = '<div class="latestf"> <a href="http://www.x.ro/anamaria/"
 rel="nofollow"';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node)
{
    $link = $node->getAttribute("href");
}

$parsed = parse_url($link);

echo substr($parsed['path'], 1, -1);
```

Output:

```
anamaria
```

### [Demo!](http://codepad.org/KJTbfSlc)

Comment: Don't use `@`. If there's an error, you should know something is wrong. Blundering along, hoping for the best can be harmful, a notice isn't (not really)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: I agree that error messages shouldn't be suppressed, but in this case, `@` sounds like a good idea since the HTML isn't properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

`/` should be escaped like this `\/`

```
<?php

  $source = '<div class="latestf"> <a href="http://www.x.ro/anamaria/" rel="nofollow"';

  preg_match_all('/<div class="latestf"> <a href="http:\/\/www.x.ro\/(.*?)\/" rel="nofollow"/', $source, $match);

  var_dump($match);exit;
```

Comment: Wrong. OP uses single quote `'` as regex delimiter.

Comment: That '.' should be escaped as '\.'